# Trimming value from a column in Snowflake

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have column called `File` with values `'Mens_Purchaser_Segment_Report'` and `'Loyalist_Audience_Segment_Report'`. I want to capture everything that comes before word Segment.

I used query:

```
select
TRIM(file,regexp_substr(file, '_Segment_Report.*')) as  new_col
```

| Output: |
| --- |
| Mens_Purch |
| Loyalist_Audi |

How do I capture everything before Segment?

Tried below but same results-->

`TRIM(file,regexp_substr(file, 'S.*'))`

`TRIM(file,regexp_substr(file, '_S.*'))`

Comment: Either you can use replace function but want more flexible can go with regex .. you can look example from @Himanshu. select replace('Mens_Purchaser_Segment_Report', 'Segment','');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify if the trailing text is always `_Segment_Report`, you're asking for any text before `_Segment`. Depending on that various solutions can be used, see below.

```
create or replace table foo(s string) as select * from values 
  ('Mens_Purchaser_Segment_Report'),
  ('Loyalist_Audience_Segment_Report');
  
-- If you know the suffix you want to remove is always exactly '_Segment_Report'
select s, replace(s, '_Segment_Report', '') from foo;

-- If you know the suffix you want to remove starts with '_Segment' but can have something after
--   - approach 1, where we replace the _Segment and anything after it with nothing
select s, regexp_replace(s, '_Segment.*', '') from foo;

--   - approach 2, where we extract things before _Segment
--     Note: it will behave differently if there are many instances of '_Segment'
select s, regexp_substr(s, '(.*)_Segment.*', 1, 1, 'e') from foo;
```

Comment: Thank you for the variety of solution. The 3rd one is what I was looking for and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

try

using regexp_replace

```
select regexp_replace(fld1, 'Segment', '') from (
select 'Mens_Purchaser_Segment_Report and Loyalist_Audience_Segment_Report' fld1 from dual );
```

Comment: That's not exactly correct, as the submission asked for the text _before_ Segment but there are additional characters there.